# A java code that identifies the loops and methods in an input text file

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, methods, preprocessor

I am having trouble with writing a successful code that identifies the loops (for loops, while loops, nested for loops) in an input text file(this input was taken using BufferedReader), and methods, where the output should look like this:

**(for loop from line x to line x)**

**(while loop from line x to line x)**

**(method xxx from line x to line x)**

I started by creating a folder that contains a text file that has a random code written in it( in my case it was a bubble sort) the code had comments, so I deleted all comments using replaceAll regex, the output with no comments is written to another .txt file, then, I used BufferedReader to read the new txt file and stored it in an ArrayList, this is where I got stuck, I tried several if statements in order to find for loops as a start.
**My question** is how can I get the desired output I wrote above?

```
   package assignment1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class tryq3 {
    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "C://myFolder//output.txt";
        Question1 DDD = new Question1();
        String source = DDD.readFile(fileName);
        String sourceNoBrackets = source.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
        
        File file1 = new File("C:\\myFolder\\cleanOutput1.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(sourceNoBrackets);
        pw.close();
        
        String line;
        int counter = 0;
        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList();
    
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\myFolder\\cleanOutput1.txt"));
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
            mylist.add(line);
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
            int count=0;
            if(mylist.get(i).contains("for")) {
                System.out.println("for loop from " + i);
                
            }
            
            
                
        }
            
            
    }
        
        
        
}
```

Comment: What kind of problem (s)? What parser are you using?

Comment: just a normal console problem nothing too complicated, I don't understand what you mean by what parser am I using.

Comment: What does your input file look like?  What is your output supposed to look like?

Comment: my input is a random java code (for example bubble sort or insertion sort) and the output as written like this: (for loop from line x to line x) (while loop from line x to line x)(method xxx from line x to line x),

Comment: You have not described the problem/issue/difficulty you are having. By “what parser” I mean how are you parsing the code.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear I am really new to java, I am first reading the random code from a txt file and just parsing it using for loop BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\myFolder\\code2.txt"));
  while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
   mylist.add(line);
  } for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
   int count=0;
   if(mylist.get(i).contains("for")) {
    System.out.println("for loop from " + i);
    
   }

Comment: What if there’s a comment in the code with the word “for”? In any case you’re still not describing the problem you’re having. The question should be edited to include the code and an actual question.

Comment: Parsing Java code is not trivial.  You have to take comments into account.  Statements can be coded on more than one line.  There are [libraries](https://javaparser.org/) that parse Java code into an abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that once the word `for` is found, don't just list the lines but locate where the open bracket `{` starts and where `}` is (ends). You can do the same for while loops and a method. You would need to catch cases where there would be a nested for loop; if `for` then `{` was found then another `for` restart the process and first state the for loop inside then the outer. I hope that helps!

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
        int count=0;
        if(mylist.get(i).contains("for") && mylist.get(i).contains("{")) {
            for(int j=i;j<mylist.size();j++) {
               if(mylist.get(j).contains("}"){
                   System.out.println("for loop from " + i);
                   i = j; // begin from where j left off
               }
               if(mylist.get(j).contains("for") && mylist.get(j).contains("{"){ // nested loop
                   for(int k=j;k<mylist.size();k++) {
                        if(mylist.get(k).contains("}"){
                             System.out.println("for loop from " + i);
                             j = k; // begin from where k left off
                        }
                   }
               
               }
            }
            
        }

}
```

Comment: What you said makes sense but to be honest, I am having trouble realizing what you said as code, would you please help me with writing the code for this? If I get the "for" loop to work I can then work on "while" loops and methods.

Comment: Sure I'll try add another answer with how to write the code

Comment: I modified this code and got the output I wanted, thanks for the help.